# Recovering a single instance with serialization

Tags: java, serialization, instance

Say I have two Objects, `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`. Both `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` have a field that stores an instance of a third class, `TestObject`. All three classes implement Serializable.

Suppose I initiate an `ObjectA` and an `ObjectB`:

```
TestObject test = new TestObject();

ObjectA aObj = new ObjectA(test);

ObjectB bObj = new ObjectB(test);
```

After this creation `aObj.getTestObject() == bObj.getTestObject()` returns `true`.

Now suppose I save aObj and bObj to files using Java serialization. When I then load the data back with deserialization `aObj.getTestObject() == bObj.getTestObject()` returns `false`. I want the object stored in aObj and bObj to remain the same object so how can I recover it as such with Java serialization i.e. `aObj.getTestObject() == bObj.getTestObject()` returns `true`?

Answer (score 1):

Well... I just answered my own question. I didn't realize that you can save multiple objects to a single file. I was saving `aObj` and `bObj` in separate files, but the reference saving only works if you save both the objects to the same file. Hopefully this saves somebody time in the future.

Comment: When you save ObjectA, you are saving multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

double equals (==) check, if both objects are the same.
you can use equals method for checking if two objects are equal.

also you can **override** equals method to provide your custom object equal check.

Comment: I want the objects to be the same. When I create the objects aObj and bObj , the TestObject inside both of them are the same i.e. one instance of TestObject put in both aObj and bObj. However, after serialization and deserialization, the link is broken and the TestObject in aObj and bObj is different. I want to preserve the link so that the TestObject is one instance for both as it was before serialization.